# Can I still file taxes and how could this affect my citizenship application?

Tags: visa, working-visas, immigration, resident-permit, canada

OK So here is my Canada Timeline:

Sept2019- Mar 2020 Closed work permit and employed

Mar 2020- Apr 2021 Closed work permit and unemployed

Apr 2021- August 2021 Open work permit and unemployed

August 2021- March 2022 Open work permit and employed

March 2022 - Present PR and employed

Now, I have never filed taxes. I intend to apply for citizenship in 2024.

1. Can I still file taxes?
2. Is my citizenship application going to be affected for late filing of taxes?
3. Any more common suggestions for me?

Comment: Is it likely that you owe taxes for any of the years you didn't pay them? Or are you probably due a refund?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all your employers deducted taxes from your paycheck, and that you haven't had any sources of income other than employment then it is most likely that the Canada Revenue Agency owes you a refund, rather than you owing them money.

In Canada it is not illegal to file a tax form late (as late as you like) **provided you do not owe taxes.** Therefore (subject to the conditions above) you have probably not committed any kind of crime. However you have let the government keep money that is due to you.

It is unlikely that this will affect your application for citizenship. Citizenship in Canada is fairly automatic provided you spend the requisite time in Canada.

However **I do strongly recommend that you file all your back taxes as soon as possible.** This should remove any doubt as to whether there is a problem. It may also get you some extra money. There is absolutely nothing to be gained by delaying. Get a tax preparer to work out taxes for all your years in Canada *before you send them off*. If they all show you deserve a refund them send them off and wait for the government to send you money. If any show that you owe money then ask your tax preparer for advice, or maybe engage a lawyer to ask what to do. Tax lawyers are good at negotiating with the CRA in circumstances like this. It is likely that if you are prepared to pay any tax you owe immediately then the consequences will not be serious.